# What's wrong with this Java program regarding TimeUnit Day conversion?

Tags: java

When I code like this I get no error :-

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


  public class DateDifference{
      public static void main(String[] main){
         String str = "20121401092958";
        /* TimeUnit spanInDays = */getDateDiff(str);
         //System.out.println(spanInDays);
      }

      public static void getDateDiff(String str ){
           DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss"); 
           Date currentDate = new Date();
           Date givenDate = null;
           Date d2 = null;
           try{
                givenDate = dateFormat.parse(str);

                long diff = currentDate.getTime() - givenDate.getTime();

                System.out.println("Days "+ TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)); 
           }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }
  }
```

but when I code it like this :-

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


  public class DateDifference{
      public static void main(String[] main){
         String str = "20121401092958";
         TimeUnit spanInDays = getDateDiff(str);
         System.out.println(spanInDays);
      }

      public static TimeUnit getDateDiff(String str ){
           DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss"); 
           Date currentDate = new Date();
           Date givenDate = null;
           Date d2 = null;
           try{
                givenDate = dateFormat.parse(str);

                long diff = currentDate.getTime() - givenDate.getTime();

                return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
           }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }
  }
```

I get **Compilation Error**

```
DateDifference.java:24: error: incompatible types: long cannot be converted to TimeUnit
                                return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                                                            ^
1 error
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is saying that the *return type* of the method is not what it expected; you declared it as `TimeUnit` but you're returning a value of type `long`.

Since that makes sense (you are returning a `long`, not a definition of a `TimeUnit`), you should adjust the return type:

```
public static long getDateDiff(String str) {
```

Comment: I thought the diff where the ^ is pointing could not be converted to TimeUnit, was finding it difficult to comprehend though.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is

`public static` **`TimeUnit`**...

So your method has to return type `TimeUnit`. What you have it returning is a `long`

`TimeUnit.Days.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` is type **`long`**

Just change the return type or what it is returning to match.

Hope this helps.